# jquery validation engine: Validate one after another

Tags: jquery, validation

I have one field for which I am running 2 validations. Is there a way I can sequence these validation check

For example:

I want to ensure that the email number is present (first check) before I check that it is valid (second check).

```
validate[required,custom[email]]
```

Currently, error messages are shown for both, but I want them to be shown only one at a time. Is this possible?

I am using jquery validation engine.

Comment: using jquery validation `user_email:{
                              required:true,
                              email:true,
                              
                            }`

Comment: You can use some other validation script.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible in *Jquery Validation* to check if value is present and if present than validate. See below example

```
 (function($, W, D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
            {
                setupFormValidation2: function()
                {
                    //form validation rules
                    jQuery("#finalise-data").validate({
                        rules: {

                                 user_phn:{
                              required:true,
                              number:true,

                            },
                           user_email:{
                              required:true,
                              email:true,

                            },
                          .
                          .
                          .
```